# Download tarball from HDFS and untar on the fly

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, tar

I am storing a large dataset as an (non-compressed) tarball inside HDFS. The tarball is roughly 250Gib in size.

I would like to download this tarball and untar it on the fly, in order to save on my machine's fast SSD. I wish to avoid first grabbing it with `hadoop fs -get ...` and then untaring it locally.

Currently, I am using `hadoop fs -cat` to grab it and pipe it to tar, using `pv` for a progress bar:

```
hadoop fs -cat my_big_tar.tar | pv -s "$TAR_SIZE" | tar xf -
```

However, when I do this, I get a few (non-fatal) errors while untaring, and the final output ends up OK, but missing some of the data (a few dozen GiB). The errors look like this:

```
Grabbing data from hadoop and untaring on the fly...                                                                     
tar: Skipping to next header============================================================>               ] 81% ETA 0:05:40
tar: Archive contains ‘\201\021\260e\210\333\357J\201\200\av’ where numeric off_t value expected        ] 81% ETA 0:05:37
tar: Archive contains ‘W\341\034\267\t\0ꑻ\317{\374’ where numeric off_t value expected                                   
tar: Archive contains ‘s{AZ\224\235 F.\317\342d’ where numeric off_t value expected======>              ] 82% ETA 0:05:10
tar: Archive contains ‘\264\357\036\272ud.W\235cL\204’ where numeric off_t value expected====>          ] 86% ETA 0:03:50
tar: Archive contains ‘\251\203\204\236\207\374\246"\255\240i\017’ where numeric off_t value expected                    
tar: Archive contains ‘T\242\b[(\372\357*e\032\255S’ where numeric off_t value expected======>          ] 87% ETA 0:03:46
tar: Archive contains ‘\300굕\277t\025o\207\373CK’ where numeric off_t value expected========>           ] 87% ETA 0:03:37
tar: Archive base-256 value is out of off_t range=============================================>         ] 88% ETA 0:03:26
tar: Archive contains ‘\204\274\234\366z\335<D\201-\306\361’ where numeric off_t value expected         ] 88% ETA 0:03:24
tar: Archive contains ‘\341ֶ\207\334-5\034\267C\v\017’ where numeric off_t value expected======>        ] 88% ETA 0:03:18
tar: Archive contains ‘c\3307\247\343ჯ\033瓸’ where numeric off_t value expected===============>         ] 89% ETA 0:03:11
tar: Archive contains ‘Vj+&!\242f$\212\374_\276’ where numeric off_t value expected=============>       ] 91% ETA 0:02:35
tar: Archive contains ‘\v5\374\273\375\302e\251ݝ\247O’ where numeric off_t value expected=======>       ] 91% ETA 0:02:33
tar: Archive contains ‘\027ȷJ\316j\203\025\027\033\264R’ where numeric off_t value expected=====>       ] 91% ETA 0:02:21
tar: Archive contains ‘Ks[L\325x\005\341\301’ where numeric off_t value expected================>       ] 92% ETA 0:02:19
tar: Archive contains obsolescent base-64 headers================================================>      ] 92% ETA 0:02:12
<snip>
tar: Archive contains ‘\177q\375\230Y<QE\0\367\242\207’ where numeric off_t value expected=============> ] 99% ETA 0:00:1
tar: Archive contains ‘\264e\260k\340,d\206\242^\022\032’ where numeric off_t value expected===========> ] 99% ETA 0:00:0
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors================================================> ] 99% ETA 0:00:0
 260GB 0:28:54 [ 154MB/s] [============================================================================>] 100%
```

Copying the data from Hadoop first, using `hadoop fs -get my_tar.tar` and then untaring works OK.

Here is my `hadoop version` output:

```
Hadoop 2.7.2
Subversion Unknown -r Unknown
Compiled by <redacted> on 2016-04-21T22:04Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum d0fda26633fa762bff87ec759ebe689c
This command was run using /opt/hadoop/hadoop-bin-2.7.2-1/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.2.jar
```

The full script is located here: https://github.com/AndreiBarsan/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/get-hdfs-tar.sh

What could be causing those errors when using `hadoop fs -cat`? (Perhaps some stray hadoop logging output getting mixed into the pipe being read by tar? How can I check for that?)

Comment: Umm. How large is the SSD? TBs? If you want speed, Hadoop supports SSD backed datanodes. Surely you can process whatever is in that file faster on multiple Hadoop nodes than your local machine?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The machine I was referring to is actually a quad-GPU VM, and at this point I would prefer training my neural network using a single node. The HDFS cluster I am using is based on HDDs, though.

Comment: What about using Spark to download the HDFS file, and process it? I actually can't recall if TAR is a "supported" file type. The recommended type of such storage for archival would be a Bzip2. For flat files HAR or sequence file

Comment: That's a very good tip. I will try that. FWIW, it's currently quite likely that the `cat` output ends up mixing the binary stream with hdfs diagnostic messages, leading to a mangled tar file.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the input; I'll try Unix & Linux!